# How does the degree of a field extension determine if it is Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> If $E/F$ is a field extension and $(E:F)=2$, is it Galois? What if $(E:F)=3$?

I don't see why the degree of the field extension matter if it is finite.

Comment: Normally information about the degree $[E:F]=n$ does not give sufficient information to decide that the extension is Galois. The case $n=2$, $\operatorname{char} F\neq2$ is the exception. Another exception would be when both $E$ and $F$ are finite (as sets). Then the extension is automatically Galois.

Answer (score 2):

$[E : F] = 2$ implies $E/F$ is Galois if $\mathrm{char} F \neq 2$.

Hint: Write $E = F(a)$, and let $f \in F[x]$ be the minimum polynomial of $a$. Then $f$ is separable, and $E$ is it's splitting field. To prove this, use the quadratic formula.

If $\mathrm{char} F = 2$, the statement is false.

Hint: Construct a degree 2 extension over $\mathbb F_2$ which isn't separable.

$[E: F] = 3$ does not imply $E/F$ Galois. A counterexample would be $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, which is a degree three extension over $\mathbb Q$, but isn't normal.